# WPF How to display a graph as a node in a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, graph, treeview

This is a design question for the collective as how to best go about the following:

I have a collection of graphs whose data gets amalgamated into an overall graph. I want to display this Overall graph as the root of a tree and when the tree is expanded all the graphs that make up the Overall Graph are displayed as child nodes.

Two other factors also need to be taken into account, firstly there could be many levels of child nodes, not just one. Secondly, I need all the graphs to line up vertically and not be indented like a standard tree, this is so all the axis's line up.

I'm currently thinking of using a grid containing two columns, a TreeView in column 0 and graphs in column 1 then add a row per graph and have the TreeView span all rows, similar to the following xaml

```
    <Grid Name="TreeGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TreeView Name="GraphTree" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Root" >
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2" />
        </TreeViewItem>

    </TreeView>

    <chartingToolkit:Chart
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Title="Sensor 2"
                    LegendTitle="Data" Margin="0,0,0,111"
                    Name="Chart1">
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    <!-- Other Chart Details -->

    <chartingToolkit:Chart
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Title="Sensor 3"
                    LegendTitle="Data" Margin="0,0,0,111"
                    Name="Chart1">
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    <!-- Other Chart Details -->

    <chartingToolkit:Chart
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Title="Sensor 4"
                    LegendTitle="Data" Margin="0,0,0,111"
                    Name="Chart1">
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    <!-- Other Chart Details -->

</Grid>
```

Apologies for the pseudoness of the xaml this is all at the design stage.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated, there must be a better way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: Wall of text, and no XAML. I'm too lazy to read thru all that. At least use some punctuaction and formatting please.

Comment: The text didn't look very inviting, apologies. I've restructured it with some xaml to hopefully make it more readable. I tried to put an image of what I'm trying to achieve which would have really helped but being relatively new on here I'm not allowed to post images - sorry.